# Still getting 'ValueError: could not convert string to float' despite trying all methods I could find to remove problematic rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file containing tens of millions of records with the user, item, and rating for each record. The ratings were scraped from the web, and were initially scraped as HTML and then replaced with the corresponding numerical rating (e.g. this is 5 stars:

"<i style=""height: 16px; width: 16px;"" class=""rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3""><i style=""height: 16px; width: 16px;"" class=""rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3""><i style=""height: 16px; width: 16px;"" class=""rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3""><i style=""height: 16px; width: 16px;"" class=""rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3""><i style=""height: 16px; width: 16px;"" class=""rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3"">"

though they were initially converted to *text* values, not floats ).

The purpose of this rating data is to run it through a matrix factorization model, and output recommendations.  To do so, I need to convert the text values for rating to numerical values (floats to be specific, as the ratings increment by 0.5).  I had previously replaced all of the HTML versions (or at least thought I had) with the corresponding text version of the number (0.5, 1, 1.5, etc.), yet when trying to convert the ratings to floats, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '<i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon60--L-GzD"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon0--1xK2J"></i>'
```

I searched through as many posts as I could find that seemed to fall into this category of error, and found three main suggestions for how to remove any remaining records with the HTML version of the rating.

```py
df[~df.rating.str.contains("icon", na=False)]

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

pd.to_numeric(df.rating, errors='coerce').dropna()
```

I have tried all three, and still, get the same error when trying to convert the ratings values to floats.  Thank you in advance for any additional suggestions as to how to get past this speed bump. I'm extremely new to python (and writing code in general) -- I took an online course and taught myself so that I could do this project on my own.  Any and all help/suggestions are extremely welcome and I am incredibly thankful for your time and thoughts.

Edit:

to answer @0x5453 's question below, code that did the initial HTML -> numerical rating conversion:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/spencermains/documents/cruu/WR_finals/trainclean_wine_reviews_red_apr2021.csv',
                     dtype={'id':str, 'winery_name':str, 'wine_name': str, 'rating':object})

dframe = df.replace('<i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon100--2vw_3"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon60--L-GzD"></i><i style="height: 16px; width: 16px;" class="rating__icon--2T9_0 rating__icon0--1xK2J"></i>', '3.5')
```

(shortened for length, but you get the idea)

Comment: Can you show the code that does the initial HTML -> numerical rating conversion?

Comment: @0x5453 - edited the post above to not be an absolute disaster like the comment was...please let me know if you have any thoughts/suggestions based on that additional information.  Thank you!

Comment: Considering the complexity of that `replace` expression I'm not at all surprised that it breaks in certain cases.  You might consider switching to a library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) that knows how to parse and traverse the HTML document tree.